# How do I determine where metadata in small allocs is stored

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I have a piece of code does hundreds of malloc and frees on small (<16) byte chunks of memory and it is failing with "invalid next size(fast)". It does not fail when run with valgrind. I added mcheck which actually does detect a failure: "memory clobbered past end of allocated block". How do I find out where this metadata is (so I can add watchpoints to it?)

Comment: mcheck complains and valgrind is silent on the exact same code?

Comment: Not only does it not complain, it completely prevents the crash.